# Column filter in ListView on win api

Tags: c, windows, listview, winapi, comctl32

I'm doing some research and I would like to know how I can implement a column filter in a ListView using purely win32 api.

Something like this:

[image]

I wrote a simple test code, to generate a List View to show the CSV content.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WND_CLASS_NAME "CSVVIEW"

char* filename;
HWND  hList;

int rgb(int r, int g, int b) { return r + (g << 8) + (b << 16); }

void onCreate(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    LVCOLUMN col;
    LVITEM item;
    int iCol, iCount, dwStyle;
    CREATESTRUCT* lp = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
    FILE* fp;
    char buf[256];
    char* field;

    memset(&item, 0, sizeof(item));
    hList = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, 0,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT,
        0, 0, 100, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)1, lp->hInstance, NULL);
    dwStyle = SendMessage(hList, LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, 0);
    dwStyle = dwStyle | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT |
        LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP;
    SendMessage(hList, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE, 0, dwStyle);
    col.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_SUBITEM;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        sprintf(buf, "Fail to open the file...", filename);
        MessageBox(hWnd, buf, "Error", MB_OK);
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(buf, 255, fp);
    field = strtok(buf, ",");
    for (iCol = 0; field != NULL; iCol++) {
        if (field[1] != ':') { col.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT; }
        else if (field[0] == 'l') { col.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;   field += 2; }
        else if (field[0] == 'c') { col.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER; field += 2; }
        else if (field[0] == 'r') { col.fmt = LVCFMT_RIGHT;  field += 2; }
        col.cx = strlen(field) * 13;
        col.iSubItem = iCol;
        col.pszText = field;
        SendMessage(hList, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, iCol, (LPARAM)&col);
        field = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    }

    item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    for (iCount = 0; fgets(buf, 255, fp) != NULL; iCount++) {
        item.pszText = strtok(buf, ",");
        item.iItem = iCount;
        item.iSubItem = 0;
        SendMessage(hList, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&item);
        for (iCol = 1; (field = strtok(NULL, ",\n")) != NULL; iCol++) {
            item.pszText = field;
            item.iItem = iCount;
            item.iSubItem = iCol;
            SendMessage(hList, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&item);
        }
    }
}

void onSize(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    MoveWindow(hList, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, TRUE);
}

int onNotify(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    NMHDR* pnmhdr = (NMHDR*)lp;
    if (pnmhdr->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {
        NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* lpCustomDraw = (NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*)pnmhdr;
        switch (lpCustomDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage) {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            if (lpCustomDraw->nmcd.dwItemSpec % 2 == 1)
                lpCustomDraw->clrTextBk = rgb(209, 240, 179);
            else
                lpCustomDraw->clrTextBk = rgb(250, 250, 250);
            return CDRF_NEWFONT;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_NOTIFY, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:  onCreate(hWnd, lParam);  break;
    case WM_SIZE:    onSize(hWnd, wParam, lParam);  break;
    case WM_NOTIFY:  return onNotify(hWnd, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0);  break;
    default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    char buf[256];
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASS wcl;
    MSG msg;

    filename = lpCmdLine;
    if (filename == NULL) return FALSE;
    InitCommonControls();

    memset(&wcl, 0, sizeof(wcl));
    wcl.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcl.lpszClassName = WND_CLASS_NAME;
    wcl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    if (!RegisterClass(&wcl)) return FALSE;

    wsprintf(buf, "%s - %s", "CSV View", lpCmdLine);
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WND_CLASS_NAME, buf,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 900, 300, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd) return FALSE;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

CSV test file:

```
COL 1,COL 2,COL 3,COL 4
CA_002,CB_002,CB_002,CB_002
CA_003,CB_003,CB_003,CB_003
```

What is necessary to change in the code so that it is possible to create the search fields in the list view header?

How to capture the events for each text field in the Header?

Comment: Add the [HDS_FILTERBAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/header-control-styles) style to your listview's header control. Last time I did this (about a month ago), I wasn't able to get the filter bar to use Visual Styles, and it looked fairly out-of-place. I didn't invest a lot of time to find out why.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks!! now I have some questions... How to get the text from the filter ?

Comment: When the filter expression changes in response to user input, a [HDN_FILTERCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/hdn-filterchange) notification is sent to the header control's parent window. This allows you to observe and respond to the updated filter. If you need to get the filter data at any other time you can send an [HDM_GETITEM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/hdm-getitem) message to the header control yourself.