# How to get the ListView handle from Header event using WinApi

Tags: c, windows, listview, winapi

Based in this question: [Column filter in ListView on win api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546226/column-filter-in-listview-on-win-api)

I modified the program (described in my first question) and now it has two ListViews ... the problem is that now I don't know how to know in which list the event occurred... the WPARAM parameter is 0 when the event is fired in the ListView filter, and in the LPARAM cast it doesn't have the ListView ID

[image]

Comment: `hwndFrom` tells you the window (i.e. the control) the message came from. `idFrom` is 0 because you haven't given your control an ID. The `HMENU` parameter of `CreateWindowEx` is used for that.

Comment: I tried to change the ID, but it keeps returning 0... it's like I need to set a ID to the ListView Header, but, there is no function or way to do this

Comment: Solved! I used this command to set a ID to the ListViewHeader: 
 SetWindowLong(hHeader, GWL_ID, 0x8803);

Comment: Sorry I missed it was the header control you were trying to identify. Better to identify it by window handle (compare `hwndFrom` with the value you get back from `ListView_GetHeader`) rather than changing the attributes of a window you didn't create.

Answer (score 1):

In a `WM_NOTIFY` message, the `NMHDR::hwndFrom` field tells you the exact control that is sending the notification, ie in this case, which exact ListView header control. You can get the `HWND` of a ListView's header control by using `ListView_GetHeader()` and then compare that to the notification's `hwndFrom`, eg:

```cpp
switch (pnmhdr->code)
{
    case HDN_FILTERCHANGE:
    {
        if (ListView_GetHeader(hwndListView1) == pnmhdr->hwndFrom)
        {
            // event happened in ListView1...
        }
        else if (ListView_GetHeader(hwndListView2) == pnmhdr->hwndFrom)
        {
            // event happened in ListView2...
        }

        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

On the other hand, since the header control is a child of the ListView, in order to even receive a `HDN_FILTERCHANGE` notification for a ListView, you have to subclass the ListView itself, as the header control will send its notifications to the ListView, not to your window.  As such, the `HWND` provided to your subclass procedure will be that of the ListView which the header notifications are being sent to, eg:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MyListViewWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ...)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            NMHDR *pnmhdr = (NMHDR*) lParam;

            switch (pnmhdr->code)
            {
                case HDN_FILTERCHANGE:
                {
                    if (hwnd == hwndListView1)
                    {
                        // event happened in ListView1...
                    }
                    else if (hwnd == hwndListView2)
                    {
                        // event happened in ListView2...
                    }

                    break;
                }

                ...
            }

            break;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Either way, as you can see, no control IDs are required.  You should not mess around with the control IDs of `HWND`s that you do not own.